# make a matrix out of 1-D arrays of array objects

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I would like to convert my 1-D arrays of array objects in a numpy matrix to perform the sum of its elements over the rows. The 1D arrays of array is:

```
 out = array([[array([0]), array([ 23.]), array([0]), array([0]),
    array([ 1.,  0.]), array([0]), array([0]), array([0])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 18.]), array([ 0.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 19.]), array([ 15.]), array([ 25.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 1.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 20.]), array([ 20.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 22.]), array([ 26.]), array([ 23.]), array([ 18.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 20.]), array([ 13.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 16.]), array([ 20.]), array([ 18.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 18.]), array([ 0.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([0]), array([ 23.]), array([0]), array([0]),
    array([ 1.,  0.]), array([0]), array([0]), array([0])]], dtype=object)
```

First I would like to sum the double values (if they exist) in the different arrays, this is the case of the first array (1+0) and the last array (1+0), to have a final 1D arrays of array with all single values:

```
 out 2 = array([[array([0]), array([ 23.]), array([0]), array([0]),
    array([ 1]), array([0]), array([0]), array([0])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 18.]), array([ 0.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 19.]), array([ 15.]), array([ 25.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 1.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 20.]), array([ 20.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 22.]), array([ 26.]), array([ 23.]), array([ 18.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 20.]), array([ 13.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 16.]), array([ 20.]), array([ 18.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 18.]), array([ 0.]),
    array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])],
   [array([0]), array([ 23.]), array([0]), array([0]),
    array([ 1.]), array([0]), array([0]), array([0])]], dtype=object)
```

Once I get "out2" I would like to make a matrix out of it (8X8 ,the last array of out2 should not be considered since is equal to the first) so that the first array of "out2" will be the first raw of the new matrix the second arrays the second raw and so on. The idea is to sum up the first two rows of the first column of the new matrix, the second two rows of the first column until the end, for all columns.

The final output should be made of 4 arrays (after the sum):

```
sum1 = [0,23,18,0,1,0,0,0]
sum2 = [0,19,35,45,0,0,0,0]
sum3 = [22,26,43,31,0,0,0,0]
sum4 = [0,23,18,0,1,0,0,0]
```

How this can be done in numpy? Thank you

Comment: If you really needs to do this. I suspect your code have a lot of problems.

Comment: It can be, I am a very beginner in numpy. Is there a way to do that without going through array->matrix conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about that `out2` with all those one-elemented `arrays`; maybe that's just an intermediate step that you do not really need. Anyhow, you can use `map` to apply `sum` to all the sub-lists in the rows. This will result in a native Python list-of-lists, which you can then turn back into a `numpy` "matrix" using `array`:

```
from numpy import array
out = array([[array([0]), ..., array([0])]], dtype=object)
matrix = array(map(lambda row: map(sum, row), out))
```

Output for `matrix`: (Alternatively, use `matrix = matrix[:-1,:]` to exclude the last row.)

```
[[  0.  23.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  18.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  19.  15.  25.   0.   0.   0.   1.]
 [  0.   0.  20.  20.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 22.  26.  23.  18.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  20.  13.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  16.  20.  18.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  18.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  23.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Now, you can use, e.g. `matrix[0:2,:]` to get the first two rows of that matrix, `transpose` them and use `map` and `sum` to get the sums of the columns. Apply `array` to get `numpy` arrays.

```
sum1 = array(map(sum, matrix[0:2,:].transpose()))
```

Of course, you can also put all those into a 4x8 matrix, by creating an `array` from a list comprehension calculating all of the above. Here, `sums[0]` would correspond to `sum1` above.

```
sums = array([map(sum, matrix[i:i+2,:].transpose()) 
              for i in range(0, len(matrix), 2)])
```

Or, much simpler, using `numpy` matrix addition, adding every other row of the matrix starting with row 0 (`matrix[0::2]`) with every other row starting at row 1 (`matrix[1::2]`):

```
sums = matrix[0::2] + matrix[1::2]
```

Output for `sums`: (Note that your `sum4` is wrong; you used rows 8 and 9.)

```
[[  0.  23.  18.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  19.  35.  45.   0.   0.   0.   1.]
 [ 22.  26.  43.  31.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  16.  38.  18.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Comment: Wouldn't be possible to iterate over the matrix and sum two rows by two with a final 4X8 matrix?

Comment: @diegus What do you mean? Do you prefer a for loop over those map/sum/zip constructs, or do you want to create all four sums in one loop? I thought you wanted to have four separate sum variables.

Comment: I would prefer to create all four sums in one loop because I will have to deal with a much bigger matrix and It would not be possible to write sum1,sum2,sum3,...sumn. Thanks a lot